# Cakephp table cells inside div

Tags: cakephp, html

I am reading some data(questions from a survey) and displaying it into table with 4 columns. 1st is displayId generated as 1,2,3,4........., 2nd column is question text and 3rd and 4th are buttons which onClick will move text, both buttons up or down through JavaScript. I want to insert 2nd, 3rd and 4th cells of every row inside div elements so that I can manipulate all 3 of them together through DOM but my div elements are getting displayed before table, not inside the table.

```
  <fieldset>
    <legend><?php __('Edit');?> 
    </legend>
    <?php $i=1;?>
       <table>
      <?php foreach ($questions as $question){ ?>
           <tr>
           <td><?php $displayId = $i; 
            echo $displayId ;?></td>
      <?php echo $this->Html->div('', null, array('id' => $i)); ?>
      <td><?php echo $question['questions']['text'];?></td>
      <td><input onClick=moveUpById() value ="up" type = "button"></td>
      <td><input onClick=moveDownById() value ="down" type = "button"></td></div> 
   </tr><?php $i++; ?><?php }?>
  </table></fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to insert 2nd, 3rd and 4th cells of every row inside div elements so that I can manipulate all 3 of them together

You can't group table cells by putting them inside a div, as you noticed. Your best approach to this is assigning a class to the cells you want to group and select them using the class.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I have done it through other way.

Answer (score 0):

don't put the div there. Use jquery selector `$("tr:not(:first-child)").click(function(){});`